# Replicating folders of web servers on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows-server-2019

I have 04 Virtual Machines(**VM**) working as Web application servers on Windows Server 2019. The VM has only one drive, that is C:. More partitions are not possible. The web application is placed in `<drv:\tomcat\...\webapps` folder of **Tomcat Server**. There are separate VMs for DB Nodes.

The webapp generates and saves Documents such as .docx, .xlsx, .pdf etc in folders inside the `appFolder` (For example, `<drv:\tomcat\...\webapps\appFolder\`).

Is there a way to replicate the saved documents of one VM Web application server with another VM server folder and vice-versa? To be more clear, I want to have same files of a folder `appFolder` irrespective on which VM that file was saved by the webapp.

My search for answers ended up with solutions for using Windows Server 2019 Distributed File System, NIC Teaming, etc. These did sound logical and workable but something seems amiss and I feel that these methods are not correct.

Also, Can there be Circular Replication? For example, Folders of VM1 gets replicated to VM2, and any new file saved on VM2 will get replicated on VM1. Is this possible?

May I get some guidance here. Thank you.

Comment: Wow, Not even a single Comment from anyone....Guys, seriously, I need help.

Comment: i used for a other reason bittorrent sync, but its changed it name these days - it uses the delta algorithm to update the files but afaik its not unidirectional, you could use in case of the same folders network shares and mounts to afford the same goal

Comment: Thanks for responding but I can't use third-party softwares.

Comment: then use dfs ;)